# Ene-yne metathesis product

Tags: organic-chemistry, organotransition-metal-chemistry

In the ene-yne metathesis how to know which product will form predominately, as the mechanisms to both are plausible?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what the R groups are and what sort of catalyst you are using.

Comment: How is that do?